# Get unique values over multiple fields

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, unique-value

For creating a legend of a map, I need to get a list of unique values over multiple attribute columns of a layer. I know how to get a list of unique values within one column - is it possible to get a list of unique values over multiple columns?

Example:
Polygon 1: Field 1: x, Field 2: a, Field 3: b

Polygon 2: Field 1: a, Field 2: c, Field 3: z

Polygon 3: Field 1: x, Field 2: b, Field 3: z

Now I need a list with the values that are unique over the fields 1, 2 and 3. For the example that would be x, a, b, c, z.

I am using QGIS Version 2.14.1

Comment: I think it would be useful to see how you are getting the unique values in one field.  The process is simple using python sets.  How are your python skills?

Answer (score 1):

Your test data (layer name: `Polygon`):

[image]

If a `Virtual Layer` is acceptable, the syntax would be:

```
SELECT Distinct(Field_1) AS Field FROM Polygon
UNION
SELECT Distinct(Field_2) AS Field FROM Polygon
UNION
SELECT Distinct(Field_3) AS Field FROM Polygon
ORDER BY Field DESC
```

Then output would be:

[image]